# server virtualization shared ram

Tags: virtualization, memory, share

My friend and I got a dedicated server. We'd like to virtualize, so that he has his own linux server and I have my own too. I'd like to share unused RAM between these two virtual machines, so I could run RAM exessive tasks when there is free RAM avaiable. 
Is it possible to share unused RAM between two or more machines?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder what the problem is with just creating two users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking if it's possible for two virtual machines on the same host to "share" RAM resources, rather than dedicating roughly half of the physical memory to each.

It is possible to do something like this on most of the major hypervisors, though it may not work exactly as you want. The feature is typically called "Memory Overcommit" or "Memory Ballooning". The way it works under the hood, is that each guest VM has a special "balloon" driver that signals to the guest operating system that it is using a chunk of memory. The driver uses a special call to the host hypervisor to inform it that the memory can be reclaimed by the hypervisor for other guests to use.

You could think of the metaphor of a physical balloon that's inside both guests. When you squeeze (deflate) the balloon in one guest, it gets bigger (inflates) in the other guest. The guests can decide how space to provide for the balloon to inflate.

There are a few issues with this scheme:

1. The balloon driver can only reclaim unused memory inside the guest, so the sharing is cooperative. If one VM has an application that happens to hold onto the memory, the other one is out of luck.
2. Not all hypervisors can inflate and deflate the memory balloon automatically. For the ones that do, it may not always inflate/deflate when you expect or want.
3. The fallback for memory overcommit when the balloon isn't able to help, is usually to use swap space on disk. If you end up having to using swap then you're probably in trouble. Performance will slow to a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

That is what virtualization is. Especially depending on your setting and the type of virtualization software you are using. The VMs will use the physical resources that are available to it. It is hard to give a good answer because you do not specify the type of virtualization software and settings you are using.